# Rails 'bundle install' command seems not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

I've encountered a problem while developing in Ruby on Rails:
After I update my app's Gemfile with a new gem dependency (for example AnnotateModel) and run 'bundle install' command the gem bin command (e.g. 'annotate'), I get a "No such file" error, so I have to add the corresponding bin folder to $PATH manually. After this tweak 'annotate' command seems to work fine. But with RSpec I get the following error: `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/bin/rspec:2:in 'require': no such file to load -- rspec/autorun (LoadError)`. How can I deal with it?
Another similar situation: I've installed 'gravatar_image_tag' similarily but when I use a view helper 'gravatar_image_tag' provided by this gem, I get an error from Rails -- undefined method.
Seems like these two problems are similar, how can I deal with them?

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
- RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rspec 2 handles Autotest differently. Read (including the comments)

http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2010/03/15/rspec-2-and-autotest/

This should resolve most of your issues. ( David Chelimsky is one of the primary developers on the rspec project )